# Why is Phoenix Armor on Saint Seiya so overpowered?

Tags: saint-seiya

Simple question:

If Golden Armors are the strongest ones, why does Phoenix Armor have more powers than they do?

Let's think together:

The Phoenix Saint will always return from dead while the Gold Saints would die only once.

Also, in the last Saint Seiya anime, we can see they colored Phoenix Armor with so much bright gold. Is there any relationship, like some history or purpose of that armor's existence?